# database in txt format with special characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that is stored in txt format.`

> https://1drv.ms/t/s!AumNXwswX2Hghlt16kqZZULWwaye

I would like to transform it to a MySQL database so that the special characters like `ā` or `ă` remain. It does not work if I just export it.

Comment: What database did you use to create the one on OneDrive

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through